# ASP.net test server on Mac OS X 10.5?

Tags: asp.net, macos, testing, webserver, xampp

is there a  build of XAMPP (or equivalent / alternative) available that has an ASP.net module for Mac OS X 10.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tutorial video on YouTube which should show you how to enable mod_mono (.NET) on Mac OS 10.5 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZjTQ1xs310Y

The transcription and guide can be found here in non-video format http://www.ienablemuch.com/2010/10/aspnet-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard-at-one.html